# SSRS, Comparing two Rows and highlight if it is zero

Tags: reporting-services

```
TOTALBILLAMOUNT TAXAMOUNT   DEPOSITE CASH
80000              0          0
90001              0          9825
100000             0          15000
110000             0          24113
120004            1000        133565
```

If Deposit is Greater than 5000 then `taxamount` should not be equals to zero. if it is zero then Change in Color is required.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the desired cell properties-> background color-> expression:

```
=IIf((Fields!DEPOSITECASH.Value > 5000) AND (Fields!TAXAMOUNT.Value = 0),"Red","Transparent")
```